# Why would this cause a latch?

Tags: fpga, verilog, latch, register, hdl

I'm reading [ZipCPU's tutorial](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/lsn-02-regs.pdf) and got confused. Specifically, I'm referring to this page.

[image]

To transcribe the Verilog code:

```
input   wire            i_S;
input   wire    [7:0]   i_V;
output  reg     [7:0]   o_R;

always @(*)
if (i_S)
        o_R = i_V;
```

I can understand that if `o_R` is declared as a `wire`, then a latch will be inferred as wires have no memory, and thus some external memory is required to keep the previous value. However, `o_R` is a register here, and registers can keep their state. For example, we can simply connect `i_S` to the "write enable" pin of the flip-flop corresponding to `o_R`, so why do we have a latch now?

As a bonus, why is a latch, rather than a flip-flop, inferred in such a situation? I'm under the impression that they basically serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `always` block is evaluated every time i_S or i_V changes. You haven't specified what the value of o_R should be when i_S is false, so the simulator and synthesizer assume that you just want to retain the old value of o_R in this case. Therefore, a latch is inserted.

The terms **latch** and **flip-flop** are not standardized, but most people use **latch** to mean a level-sensitive bistable element while a **flip-flop** is an edge-sensitive bistable element. They are not the same.

Comment: "you just want to retain the old value of o_R" I understand this, but registers/flip-flops (which I assume would be inferred from the keyword `reg`) are born to retain their previous value! Why do we need an additional latch then?

Comment: No, you are mistaken about the `reg` keyword, it does not infer a latch by default. Latch inference is determined by the behavior of the HDL code.

Comment: Hi Alderson, please kindly re-read my comment (and preferably the question too). Would `reg` definitely infer a register/flip-flop (not latch)? Speaking of the behavior, AFAIK `o_R` is required to keep its previous value because `reg` is used, so it will infer a register/flip-flop.

Comment: **NO**, `reg` does **not** definitely infer a flip-flop or a latch. The keyword `reg` defines something that acts like a regular variable in a typical programming language, meaning that it allows sequential evaluation within an `always` block. But a latch or flip-flop is only inferred if the **behavior** of the code indicates that a latch or flip-flop is required. One last time...using `reg` **does not** inherently cause a latch or flip-flop to be inferred.

Comment: Thanks, let's see if my understanding is correct now: so I write Verilog to specify the behavior, and the synthesizer will figure out which hardware to use to fulfill my requirement. In the code above, `always @(*)` requires `o_R` to change when any input is changed, so a level-sensitive latch is inferred instead of an edge-sensitive flip-flop (we don't even have a CLK signal here!). In addition, if I add `o_R = 0` just above the `if (i_S)` line, neither latches nor flip-flops will be inferred despite the keyword `reg`, because the behavior can be fulfill with purely combinational logic.

Comment: Yes, except for a minor clarification. The `always @(*)` does not **require** that `o_R` **change** when any input changes, it requires that the body of the always block be **evaluated** when any input changes. The value of `o_R` will change only if the statements in the body of the block cause it to change. Yes, if you add a default or `else` value for `o_R` then a latch will not be inferred.

Comment: Great explanation! It turns out that `reg`/`wire` doesn't really maps to real flip-flops/wires, and Verilog is used to describe the behavior rather than the circuitry. That's really helpful to know.

Answer (score 1):

First: the 'reg' keyword in Verilog has little to do with the final circuit. I can produce registers but also combinatorial logic.... and latches. It **is** confusing and I assume the main the reason why in System Verilog they switched to the 'logic' type.

Register outputs only change on a clock edge (or asynchronous reset/set). They keep their output value even if the input changes.

A latch does not. As long as your `I_s` is high the `o_R` will change if the `I_V` changes. We say that "`o_R` *follows* the `I_V`".

Thus a register and latch definitely do not serve the same purpose.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why do we need to care about what happened between two `posedge`s? I mean, even flip-flops have setup/hold time, but people don't seem to care about that. I assume we just need to make sure the values are "correct" at each `posedge`, because that is all what our code asks for?

Comment: @nalzok In the real world, people care very, very much about setup and hold time.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks for the explanation. I just realized that timing analysis is at least partially based on setup and hold time. Maybe I can even say people don't need to care about them *because* timing analysis ensures the signals will be stable at each clock edge.